# Which forum software has a "like/don't like button" in the post (and other features)?

Tags: wordpress, looking-for-a-script, forum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I want to build a new blog (on Wordpress) and I want to insert a forum in the website.
I don't want to use PhpBB for the forum section (too complex to configure and manage) and I'm searching a simple solution.

The feature I absolutly need:

- like/don't like button in every post
- polls
- attachment and image upload
- tag system for the post

Other appreciate features:

- import post from another PhpBB forum
- FB connect (for the user login)
- integration with wordpress
- reserved section (for only a group of user)

At the moment I have found these solutions:

- bbpress: all feature above but it doesn't have the "like/don't like" button
- OSQA: I don't know if have the pools and attachment function

Anyone can help me and suggest other solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) has all of those features, though you will need to install the [voting plugin](http://vanillaforums.org/addon/voting-plugin) and a [poll plugin](http://vanillaforums.org/addon/browse/all/popular/2?Form/Keywords=poll) to get the poll and like/dislike feature.